# -c flag missing from su under macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, su

I am using El Capitan 10.11.6 and need to use `su -c` to run `psql` as the `_postgres` user. The problem is, this flag is absent on my version of macOS. Can't speak for other newer versions of macOS (currently don't have access to newer OSes). Is there any alternative? I need to use this in both a script and on the command line.

Correction, a read through the man pages a bit more closely than before revealed that `su` does in fact have a `-c` flag, however it doesn't seem to work for me. Running `su _postgres -c 'mkdir /Users/leetbacoon/folder'` doesn't work or display anything to the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Debian `man 1 su` reads:

> an argument of `-c` will cause the next argument to be treated as a command by most command interpreters. The command will be executed by the shell specified in `/etc/passwd` for the target user.

Most likely the situation is the same on macOS. The user you provide to `su` probably has `/bin/false` specified in `/etc/passwd`. This is normal for system users. This way nobody can directly log in as such user. This is a Good Thing.

I guess you're invoking the command as root, so there is no password prompt. What happens under the hood is:

```
/bin/false -c 'mkdir /Users/leetbacoon/folder'
```

This command is completely silent, only its exit code (`1`) indicates failure. Your `su` reports the same exit value.

---

Use `sudo`:

```
sudo -u _postgres mkdir /Users/leetbacoon/folder
```

`_postgres` may not be allowed to create a directory inside `/Users/leetbacoon/`. If so, you will get an error from `mkdir`. Still `mkdir` itself will run.